# Copy files in same folder and replace year in its name

Tags: bash, cp

How can I copy a lot of files in the same directory replacing the year in its name?

I have this (can be different filename and extensions):

```
filename1-2014.ext
filename2-2014.ext
filename3-2014.ext
...
filenamen-2014.ext
```

And I want this:

```
filename1-2014.ext
filename1-2015.ext
filename2-2014.ext
filename2-2015.ext
filename3-2014.ext
filename3-2015.ext
...
filenamen-2014.ext
filenamen-2015.ext
```

I can make a script to do it, but I'm wondering is there is an easy way of doing it?

Comment: Also have a look at the `rename` tool. (The one that comes with perl.)

Comment: @michas +1 for reminder of this tool. `rename 2014 2015 *`.

Comment: `rename` is not an option, as I need to copy the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With find:

  ```
  find . -type f -name '*2014*' -exec bash -c 'cp "$0" "${0/2014/2015}"' {} \;
  ```
- In the shell loop:

  ```
  for file in *2014*; do
      cp "$file" "${file/2014/2015}"
  done
  ```

Comment: Works similarly with `ag` and `xargs` too: `ag -g 2014 | xargs -I % bash -c 'cp "$0" "${0/2014/2015}"' %`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *-2014.ext; do
  cp "$i" "${i%2014.ext}2015.ext"
done
```

For each file remove the old suffix and add the new one.

If you have different extensions you can use the pattern substitution feature of bash:

```
for i in *-2014.*; do
  cp "$i" "${i/2014/2015}"
done
```

Comment: I suppose that this works if the extension is the same for all file, but what about if is different? Sorry, I update my question.